# Angular $filter not available in promise callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, closures

I'm injecting $filter into my controller and all is well until I try to use it in a promise callback. Here's the gist of the code

```
controller: ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {
  geozipcodes.featured().$promise.then(function(res){
    $scope.item = $filter('unique')(res, 'name');
  });
}]);
```

This throws 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $filter is not defined'

However, if I do this

```
controller: ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {
  var $filter = $filter;
  geozipcodes.featured().$promise.then(function(res){
    $scope.item = $filter('unique')(res, 'name');
  });
}]);
```

Everything works as expected which I don't get at all. I should mention this is inside of an if/else statement, but that shouldn't have any bearing I don't think.

Has anyone experienced anything similar? The way I'm solving it feels really hacky plus I don't really understand why it works.

Update: more code for context

```
angular.module('ourApp').directive('searchItems', ['$timeout', '$rootScope', 'geozipcodes', 'baselistings', '$compile', '$stateParams',
function($timeout, $rootScope, geozipcodes, baselistings, $compile, $stateParams) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            performSearch: '&',
            emptySetMessage: '@',
            itemType: '@',
            searchTrigger: '=',
            toggleToolbar: '@',
            noResults: '=?'
        },
        templateUrl: 'views/directives/search-items.html',

        controller: ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'utils', 'companies', 'settings', 'geozipcodes', '$stateParams', '$filter',
            function($scope, $rootScope, utils, companies, settings, geozipcodes, $stateParams, $filter) {

                $scope.settings = settings;
                $scope.searchType = $scope.itemType == 'student' || $scope.itemType == 'applicant' ? 'student' : $scope.itemType == 'listing' || $scope.itemType == 'application' || $scope.itemType == 'invitation' ? 'listing' : ''
                $scope.items = []
                $scope.searchInProgress = true;
                $scope.initFilters = {};
                $scope.pageFilters = {};
                $scope.sortList = [];

                if ($scope.searchType == 'first') {
                    // omitted
                } else {
                    if ($scope.itemType == 'listing') {
                        listingtags.categories().$promise.then(function(res) {
                            $scope.tagCategories = res;
                        });
                        geozipcodes.featured().$promise.then(function(res){
                            $scope.defaultLocations = $filter('unique')(res, 'name');
                        });
                    }
                }
...
```

Comment: First snippet should work fine, `$filter` is accessible will be accessible in the callback. Can you replicate it?

Comment: Yeah, it's happening consistently each time.

Comment: Can you provide more code? I'm curious about this last closing brace. It should work in the first case. I assume that this is a controller for a directive or route. Do you use $filter somewhere above?

Comment: @Mate Added more code for context. $filter is not used anywhere above

Comment: It's not about context, it's about constructor function where you declared new promise instance

Comment: Such side effects are avoided by assigning $filter to this.$filter etc. I guess you saw such code.

Comment: Here you have a variable. There are no problems with `this` or sth similar. I don't have an idea :(